# How to remove the "custom" block from header section of the Zonda theme

Tags: magento-1.9, theme, header

I am begining to build a Magento website and I can't seem to figure out to how remove the "custom" tab on the header. Any ideas?

http://www.everythingcarol.com/

Here's the website for reference.

[image]

Surprisingly, it's not in the header:

```
<?php 
$zonda = $this->helper('zonda');
$containerClass = $zonda->getContainerClass();
$b = $zonda->getConfigGroup();
$switcher_html = $this->getChildHtml('currency') . $this->getChildHtml('store_language');
$cart_html = $this->getChildHtml('cart_sidebar');
?>
    <?php if ($b['header']['header_type'] == 'type1'):?>    
    <div class="container clearfix">
        <div class="mobile-block-container clearfix">
            <div class="block block-minicart">                        
                <?php echo $cart_html; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="block-switcher clearfix">                    
                <?php echo $switcher_html ?>         
            </div>
        </div>       
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
            <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $zonda->getLogo() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo-img"/></a></h1>            
        <?php else:?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $zonda->getLogo() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo-img"/></a>
        <?php endif?>            
        <div class="header-right">
            <div class="header-top">
                <div class="left">                    
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>    
                </div>
                <div class="right clearfix block-container">
                    <div class="block block-minicart">                        
                        <?php echo $cart_html; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="block-switcher clearfix">                    
                        <?php echo $switcher_html ?>         
                    </div>               
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mobile-bg"></div>
            <div class="header-menu-back">
                <div class="header-menu-container clearfix">
                    <h1 class="sticky-logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="sticky-logo"><img src="<?php echo $zonda->getLogo() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo-img"/></a></h1>
                    <div class="header-menu clearfix">
                        <div class="quick-access">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>                    
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>                                    
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>        
    <?php else: ?>        
    <div class="header-top">
        <div class="container clearfix">
            <div class="left">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="right clearfix">
                <div class="block block-minicart">                        
                    <?php echo $cart_html; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="block-switcher clearfix">
                    <?php echo $switcher_html ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-bg"></div>
    <div class="header-menu-back">
        <div class="header-menu-container clearfix">   
            <div class="header-menu header-menu-right clearfix">
                <div class="container clearfix">
                    <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $zonda->getLogoBg() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="pos-abs logo-bg-img"/><img src="<?php echo $zonda->getLogo() ?>" class="logo-img"/></a></h1>
                    <div class="mobile-toplinks">
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
                    </div>            
                    <div class="header-right clearfix">
                        <div class="quick-access">
                            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>                    
                        </div>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>                    
                    </div>            
                </div>        
            </div>        
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: is it possible this theme have admin demo ? may be some static block has been created like top-menu

Comment: kindly show your header section code>You can remove block is layout xml code.

Comment: Hmm... not in the header surprisingly.

Comment: Iam assuming `custom` is called using a `static block` check your `static blocks`

Comment: Aw... Thanks dh47. Got it. Still learning all this Magento stuff. You just saved me a lot of time :)

Comment: @HomeroMiranda check my answer for clear explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just know gone through that theme live preview and description and noticed it is using `mega menu` for getting menu and for your particular problem do in this way. Goto `CMS->static Blocks` find for `custom` block and disable it.Your issue will be solved.

[image]